# Clojure Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when posting a request

Tags: clojure, cors, clojurescript

I have a simple `clojure` back end which is running on `localhost:8090` and a simple `clojurescript` front end running on `localhost:3449`.

The idea is that upon clicking a button the front end will send a `POST` request to an API endpoint on the backend and do the appropriate action. If i use postman and send a request to the backend then everything works as expected.

The problem is when sending this request (using `cljs-http`)

```
(defn send-data []
    (http/post "http://localhost:8090/send-email" {:json-params {:subject "post from cljs"}}))
```

The Chrome console reports:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/send-email. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3449' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

From my understanding I need to define `CORS` within my application and I did so as seen [here](https://www.refheap.com/36765) The problem with this is that once this is implemented the `POST` requests from postman no longer work so it breaks the application.

My app is defined as follows:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (redirect "/index.html"))
  (GET "/emails" [] "emails")

  (POST "/send-email" {body :body} (do
                                     (send-email (json/read-str (slurp body)
                                                   :key-fn keyword))
                                     "OK"))
  (POST "/add-recipient" {body :body} (do
                                        (add-recipient (json/read-str (slurp body)
                                                         :key-fn keyword))
                                        "Recipient Added"))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (->
    (wrap-defaults app-routes api-defaults)
    (wrap-resource "public")
    (wrap-resource "/META-INF/resources")
    ))
```

I also tried this configuration based off of the `Ring CORS` github page:

```
(def app
  (->
    (wrap-defaults app-routes api-defaults)
    (cors/wrap-cors my-routes :access-control-allow-origin [#".*"]
                         :access-control-allow-methods [:get :put :post :delete])
    (wrap-resource "public")
    (wrap-resource "/META-INF/resources")
    ))
```

which doesnt even compile `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: [:get :put :post :delete]` is thrown.

How can I implement it so it accepts requests from `localhost:3449` which will send a `JSON` post body without breaking current functionality.

Edit:

These are the response headers from postman when executing a request:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Response headers 
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 10:07:31 GMT 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3449
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 2 
Server: Jetty(7.6.13.v20130916)
```

Comment: Dont add `my-routes` to the `wrap-cors` when you're `->` your form

Answer (score 0):

what's `my-routes`?

Try

```
(-> app-routes 
  (wrap-defaults api-defaults)
  (cors/wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin [#".*"]
                  :access-control-allow-methods [:get :put :post :delete])
  (wrap-resource "public")
  (wrap-resource "/META-INF/resources")
)
```